# linux - curl read in file attribute from a file

Tags: linux, curl, api

So I have this curl command.  But I want to store the API-key in a file called api.txt and have it load where the  value is in the curl command.

api.txt files contains

```
'X-Api:<API-KEY>'
```

This command works.

```
curl -H 'X-Api:<API-KEY>' -T file.zip "https://URL"
```

Tried:

```
curl -H “Content-Type: text/plain” -d “api.txt” -T file.zip "https://URL"
```

Got error:

```
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Unauthorized"
  } ]
}%
```

Question:

1. How can I load either the actual api key or the expected line from api.txt to parse it into the curl command?
2. is this the way to do this? or a better way?

Comment: `-d` isn't going to work.  `-d` sends POST request data.  Your API seems to want the API Key in a HTTP request header (the `-H` option). HTTP request headers and POST data are two completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -H "$(cat api.txt)" -T file.zip "https://URL"
```

Alternatively, to remove all percent symbols and single-quotes from input file:

```
curl -H "$(tr -d "'%" api.txt)" -T file.zip "https://URL"
```

or, to remove only the `'` at the start and the `'%` at the end:

```
curl -H "$(sed -E "s/^'|'%$//g" api.txt)" -T file.zip "https://URL"
```

---

PS: I initially thought that this needed to be done in two lines, in order to avoid the trailing newline in api.txt:

```
API_KEY=$(cat api.txt)
curl -H "$API_KEY" -T file.zip "https://URL"
```

But bash seems to have improved its handling of newlines at the end of the input file in [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) - i.e. it strips them if there's no further input.  I'm using bash 5.1.16, you may have to use the two-line version if you're using a different shell or a different version of bash.

Comment: `-H "$(cat api.txt)"` seems an expensive way to do `-H '@api.txt'` where `curl` reads the file itself.

Comment: One `cat` process doesn't seem particularly expensive to me.  Certainly less expensive than spending time learning about a minor convenience feature that only works in one particular program rather than a general-purpose shell feature like command substitution that works for pretty much everything.

Comment: I still get the same error but I noticed when I "cat api.txt". There is a % at the end ex 'X-Api:<API-KEY>'% which might be the extra character that is cause the error.  Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: either edit the file to remove the `%` symbol, or use `$(sed -e 's/%$//' api.txt)` instead of `$(cat api.txt)`.

Comment: Ok used truncate -s -1 api.txt to remove that last character but % wasn't the last character it was actually '.  So that means it's not working.

Comment: ok this actually worked as it suppose to.  Seems like the GUI text editor that I used for some reason adds a % to the end. But when I created strictly through the commandline, it worked as desired.  thanks!

Comment: You probably want to get rid of the leading `'` too. Try `API_KEY=$(tr -d "'%" api.txt)`. Note, it's a little difficult to read, but there's a single-quote AND a percent symbol inside those double-quotes. Also note that this will delete ALL such characters. If your API key contains, or might contain `%` or `'` then use `API_KEY=$(sed -E "s/^'|'%$//g" api.txt)`

Comment: ATcas thanks for the direction @thrig if you can add your solution of curl -H '@api3.txt' -T api2.zip "https://URL" then I can accept it.

Comment: The `@api.txt` thing won't work if the file contains the quotes or percent. You need to get rid of them first.

Comment: @cas You're right it didn't take when I parsed it but I compensated that by adding it in the command line.  Which took.  The % seemed to be an artifact of the GUI editor I used.  Using fully command line that didn't generate.

Answer (score 1):

`curl` supports `@` to read the headers from a correctly formatted file;
this will be more efficient than a forking out to `cat` and may allow
the shell to be eliminated in favor of the simpler, more efficient, and
less prone to security flaws `exec(3)` call to run `curl` instead of
needing `system(3)` and a shell:

```
curl -H '@api.txt' -T file.zip "https://..."
```

The `@` does not need quoting for a simple Bourne shell but is here to
guard against some shell doing something with that character. If a fancy
shell (e.g. `zsh`) is being used check the rules on quoting to see which
characters have special meaning, or proactively quote everything.

Comment: this was the closest solution curl -H @api.key -T file.zip "https://"